# How can lines be smoothed in Freestyle?

Tags: rendering, freestyle

For example the lines on this monkey render show pointed edges instead of a smooth curves. How can the lines come out more smooth?
[image: Freestyle Monkey][image: Current Line Art]
Current Line
[image]
Smooth Line

Comment: By using a more detailed model - using a Subdivision Surface modifier...

Comment: Just select the model and hit [Ctrl]+[2]. this should make it a lot smoother. You can also enable smooth shading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apart from smoothing the mesh with Subsurf, 
you could also try adding a Bezier Curve Modifier to the Geometry of the Line Style:

[image]

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

You can also tweak the result by adjusting the chain angles:

[image]